# lapply? and recursive partial replacement, data frame

Tags: r, recursion, multiple-columns, lapply

I want to streamline pattern matching for updating data frames. For example, a zero needs to be tacked on to all the single characters, fields 2 & 3:

```
set.seed(5)
x<-data.frame(Site=c(rep("Site A",5),rep("Site B",5)),
  Upstream=rep(c("A5","B","B5","C","C5"),2),
  Downstream=rep(c("A","A5","B","B5","C"),2),
  Value=sample(100:200,10), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)
```

This solution works fine, field by field:

```
r<-data.frame(V1=LETTERS[1:11],V2<-paste0(LETTERS[1:11],"0"), stringsAsFactors=FALSE)                 
replc<-r[,2][match(x[,3],r[,1])]
x[,3]<-ifelse(is.na(replc),x[,3],replc)
```

For multiple fields, these list-based attempts give kind of interesting results but not what I want:

```
s2<-LETTERS[seq(1:11)]
lapply(s2,function(z){replace(x[,3],x[,3]==z,paste0(z,"0"))})                  
lapply(s2,function(z){x[,3][x[,3]==z]<-paste0(z,"0")})                         
lapply(s2,function(z){x[x[,3]==z,]<-paste0(z,"0");x} )                        
lapply(s2,function(z){within(x,x[,3][x[,3]==z]<-paste0(z,"0"))} )               
lapply(s2,function(z){(with(x,{x[x[,3]==z,]<-paste0(z,"0")}))} )
```

With trial and error a variation on the above has worked but then I get NAs for the non-matches (all values ending in 5). So, I'm at least missing a couple pieces such as recycling the df & dealing with the NAs.

If the above works then I wanted to just cycle though many fields with the replacements along the lines of:

```
lapply(x[,2;3], function(y){
        lapply(s2,function(z){x[,y][a[,y]==z]<-paste0(z,"0")})      
        })
```

Thanks for any assistance.

Comment: Or, similar to Jimbou's suggestion: `x[] <- lapply(x, function(y) ifelse(nchar(y) == 1, paste0(y, 0), y))`

Comment: I dropped a parentheses.  Sorry.  Yes, those suggestions look like they should work.  Thanks for the assistance.

Comment: I was missing parentheses, sorry.  Yes those suggestions look like they should work.  Thanks for the assistance.  The issue is more general though as not all the character strings end in 5.

Answer (score 3):

I would do...

```
mycols = 2:3
x[, mycols] <- lapply(x[, mycols], function(z) sub("^(.)$", "\\10", z))
```

which gives

```
     Site Upstream Downstream Value
1  Site A       A5         A0   120
2  Site A       B0         A5   168
3  Site A       B5         B0   190
4  Site A       C0         B5   127
5  Site A       C5         C0   110
6  Site B       A5         A0   167
7  Site B       B0         A5   150
8  Site B       B5         B0   175
9  Site B       C0         B5   188
10 Site B       C5         C0   196
```

This uses a regex to identify single characters `.` that make up the full string -- from start `^` to finish `$`. The parentheses identify a "group" that is referred to in the replacement by `\\1`.

Comment: Great.  Giving it a try.

Comment: Just what I wanted.  I can just wrap that in my list of data frames and filter to the fields to update.

Comment: That regex comment is useful.  I can combine that with a filter.  So, would this mean two characters (..) and this \\20 mean add zero as a third character?

Comment: @user2009447 For two characters, yeah, that should work. `"^(..)$"` as the pattern and `"\\10"` as the replacement (since the \\1 "backreference" refers to the "group" counter, which just depends on the parentheses in the pattern). Instead of writing out each dot, you could use a quantifier, like `"^(.{2})$"`, too. For more details, try `?regex` in R or any online resource on regexes (since they're similar in other languages).

Answer (score 2):

Without regex you can use this:

```
mycols = 2:3
x[, mycols] <- apply(x[,mycols], 2, function(x) ifelse(nchar(x)<2, paste0(x,0), x))
```

The function paste a `0` behind the string if the length of the string is smaller than 2. As commented by docendo discimus you can also use `nchar(x) == 1` to search for strings exactly having length of 1.

Comment: Giving this one a try too.  Thanks.

Comment: `lapply` is preferred over `apply` for this sort of thing, since the latter combines the columns into a matrix and returns a matrix (which must then be split back into columns when assigned to `x`).

Comment: This also works fine, and I can modify it for more general solutions and a list of data frame.s

Comment: Actually I can see now some similarity with this approach to some tallies and tests for NAs I was working on recently for a different set of data frames.  cols<- c(3:7);
lapply(cols,function(z) {count(y<-x[,z])})  ;  x["sum_"]<- apply(x[,cols],1,function(y) length(which(!is.na(y))))